# Connect to SQL Server 2014 in Go Lang

Tags: sql, go, driver, sql-server-2014

I had a working database connection on a windows 7 machine to SQL Server 2008 R2 using:

```
     db, err = sqlx.Open("lodbc", connString)
```

importing the following packages

```
     "github.com/LukeMauldin/lodbc"
     "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
```

But now using the same driver and changing the connection string to a 2014 SQL Server database located on a remote windows 8 machine, I get a successful connection but a sqlx query breaks saying

> datasource 2015/03/23 09:09:37 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:49346: {IM002} [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Is there another driver I can use? I tried [code.google.com/p/odbc](https://code.google.com/p/odbc/) and database/mssql packages and those didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: why doesn't `database/mssql` work?

Comment: For some reason I got undefined config errors in the mssql package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [database/sql](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) with the [github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb) driver.

Comment: It's the same issue.  I think it has something to do with setting up an odbc on the remote sql server and setting the right group permissions.

Comment: I changed the driver and it connected. Thank you!!

Comment: All of the documentation is god awful... Why doesn't is exact the EXACT connection string from my DB? Every "guide" you read is completely different. Does no one actually know the best wa yto do this yet or something?